# select mysql group by not work

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a select mysql, the table is this:

```
id_type |  id_funz | state    
10           26        1
10           28        1
11           26        1
```

I want to select id_type (with group by) who have both (id_funz 26 and 28) in state = 1, in practice only id_type = 10

why this not work?

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE
(id_funz = 26 AND state = 1) and ((id_funz= 28 AND state = 1)
group by id_type
```

thank you so much

Comment: Usually you only use group by if you’re gonna use some aggregate function like count or sum. Why are you trying to use group by here?

Comment: please post sample of expected results.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I would like as a result only because it is the only id_type = 10 one that has id_funz 26 and 28

Answer (score 0):

`id_funz = 26` and `id_funz = 28` cannot happen at a same time. Change your code to :

```
(id_funz = 26 AND state = 1) OR (id_funz= 28 AND state = 1)
```

Comment: hi, 
it does not work, so I also select id_type = 11, I do not want it